# How do I elevate a c# process at runtime

Tags: c#, elevated-privileges

Purely for reasons of my own curiosity, I am attempting to create a console application in c# that will elevate itself if it sees that it is not running as admin.

The code that I have at the moment is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace SelfElevator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!IsAdmin())
            {
                ProcessStartInfo proc = new()
                {
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                    FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location,
                    Verb = "runas"
                };

                try
                {
                    Process.Start(proc);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool IsAdmin()
        {
            WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new(id);
            return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to execute this I receive the error `"No application is associated with the specified file for this operation."`

I have done some googling and have concluded that perhaps this might be connected to the use of the `runas` verb. How and why (and what I might do to correct) though is still eluding me. Note that I am explicitly not including an `application.manifest` as I want the application to start unprivileged, detect that it is in that state then restart itself elevated. I also do not mind dealing with the appearance of a UAC prompt. I'm not trying to hack systems - I would just like to understand how to accomplish this process.

Comment: A Net application running in VS will not run As Admin by default.  The executable will.  To start VS with As admin right click the shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @OlivierRogier your link provided the answer. If you would like to post a solution I will be happy to accept it.